# Clear value PeoplePicker in JavaScript (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

Please tell me how to clear the value PeoplePicker in JavaScript (JQuery)? Tried a lot of examples, nothing works.

```
$("input[id*='Author']").val('');
$("div[id*='Author']").attr('description','');
$("div[id*='Author']").attr('displaytext','');
$("div[id*='Author']").attr('key','');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what you are trying to accomplish as **Author** is the internal name for the field **Created By** but here goes.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

/*Finds and deletes the resolved users in the people picker control "Test" if there are more than zero user present.*/ 

$(document).ready(function() {
peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$('[Title*="Test"]')[0].id];
    if (peoplePicker.TotalUserCount > 0) {
        peoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Cristoffer Failed to get the "TotalUserCount" property of a reference whose value is not defined or is NULL

Comment: Think i missed out 2 references.. try again. Or are you trying to manipulate the created by field? The field need to be in the actual form. If the reference is null = field not found.

Comment: @Cristoffer Tried different options, even created a field people picker "Test", the same mistake "Failed to get the TotalUserCount" property of a reference whose value is not defined or is NULL"

Comment: Can you debug? What SharePoint version? Should have specified that this is for 2013, hence the reference to _layouts/15.

Comment: Reference it's Ok, SharePoint 2013 Ent., debug only same error...

Comment: Breakpoints? is the variable "peoplePicker" empty?

Answer (score 0):

Following scripts works for me for ClientPeoplePicker. The `DeleteProcessedUser` method requires `span` element of resolved user.

**Definition:**

```
function removeAllUsers(peoplePickerId){
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_" + peoplePickerId + '_TopSpan'];

    var selectedUsers = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var userToRemoveKey = selectedUsers[1].Key; 

    var resovledListElmId = peoplePicker.ResolvedListElementId;
    $('#' + resovledListElmId).children().each(function(index, element) {
        peoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser(element);
    });
}
```

**Usage:**

```
removeAllUsers("PeoplePickerControlName");
```

Comment: Your code does not understand the connection between my Title field "Author"? The normal column that is created in the list and fill in Newform.aspx, JS code is added via Content Editor. There is not project VS.